# Sklearn scaler attribute changes when returned : X has 6 features, but MinMaxScaler is expecting 1 features as input

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, attributes, return

I recently encountered a puzzling problem with Sklearn, and even if it's not that hard to bypass it, I'd like to understand what's going on.

So the problem is that I get the error `ValueError: X has 6 features, but MinMaxScaler is expecting 1 feature as input.` when I try to transform any dataset with a scaler object returned by a function in which I previously fitted it (fit_transform) on a dataset with 6 features.

If I try to use the scaler inside that function and on any dataset, it either runs fine if the given dataset has 6 features, or raises the error `ValueError: X has Y features, but MinMaxScaler is expecting 6 features as input.`, with Y being the features number from the input.

So it seems that as soon as I return the object, the `n_features_in` attribute is set to 1. The other attributes don't change and if I manually set the `n_features_in` attribute to 6 everything seems to work fine.

So the question is: what is going on?

**Edit:** Did a little bit of testing and the other attributes do change. The data_max_ attribute which normally is a list of len 6 becomes a list of len 1, containing the max value of the first feature of the train set.

Here is a simplified code snippet to help understand the code structure :

```
def construct(dataset, scaler_type) :

    scaler = scaler_type

    scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)

    print(scaler.n_features_in_) #Prints 6

    scaler.transform([[1,2,3,4,5,6]]) #Works fine

    return scaled_data, scaler

scaled_data, scaler = construct(dataset, MinMaxScaler())

print(scaler.n_features_in_) #Prints 1

scaler.transform([[1,2,3,4,5,6]]) #Raises error : ValueError: X has 6 features, but MinMaxScaler is expecting 1 features as input.
```

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

I solved the problem, and hopefully (even though I doubt many will encounter the same) the solution will be useful to others.

Unless a superhuman intuition, the simplified code snippet I provided wouldn't have been enough to find where the problem came from ( I should have at least run it myself smh...). And that is because, in the actual code, I declare two separate scalers, one for the x train data, and one for the y train data.

```
def construct(dataset, scaler_type):
    xscaler, yscaler = scaler_type, scaler_type
    
    #do things...

    x_set = xscaler.fit_transform(dataset)

    #taking first feature as y data
    y_set = yscaler_fit_transform(dataset[:,0])
    
    scaled_data = (x_set, y_set)

    return scaled_data, xscaler, yscaler
```

The issue here is that when I called the function, I passed the arguments like the following :

```
scaled_data, xscaler, yscaler = construct(dataset, MinMaxScaler())
```

Notice how I instantiate the MinMaxScaler Class in the function call. This causes the `xscaler` and `yscaler` variables two refer to the same object inside the function, causing the attributes from `xscaler.fit_transform()`
to be lost when I call the `yscaler.fit_transform()` method.

**Passing the MinMaxScaler class instead of instantiating it in the function call solves the issue.**